# Set Name and Email setup depending on git repo?

Tags: git, github

I have two github accounts, 1 for personal and other one for work.

If I git clone repo from my work github account, is there a way automatically set `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` for work config?

Answer (score 2):

You can put some logic in a post-checkout hook, which will be run after a clone.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh                      

die() { test -n "$*" && echo "$@" >&2; exit 1; }                   
if test "$1" = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000; then  
        url=$(git ls-remote 2>&1 > /dev/null | awk '{print $2; exit}')                                                   
        test -n "$url" || die Cannot find url of remote               
        case $url in           
        *unique_string*)                 
                git config user.email hello@world.org          
                git config user.name Hello World               
                ;;             
        esac                   
fi
```

In this case, pick some string from your work url that you can use to recognize the repo.  In order to get this hook to run after a clone, you'll need to configure git to use it, and that's probably easiest to do by using a template dir.  That is, put the above script in `$HOME/.config/git-templates/hooks/post-checkout` (or wherever you would like, and don't forget to chmod +x) and run `git config --global init.templatedir '~/.config/git-templates'`

You can probably avoid the `ls-remote` cruft and just reference `origin`, but that will fail if you've used `--origin` in clone to use a non-default name.  There's probably (undoubtedly) a cleaner way to get the remote url than filtering the output of ls-remote, but that's a different question.  I'm sure a better solution will be found in the comments in the near future!

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by writing the custom script which will automatically run and configure git config when you switch to your project directory. 
just like `rvmrc file which configures gemset`

for writing script you can refer below link: 
Refer this https://willi.am/blog/2015/02/27/dynamically-configure-your-git-email/